# Can I run an Activity before running libgdx?

Tags: android, bluetooth, libgdx

Since I have exception running 
`mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();`
in libgdx's render(),
I have an idea to run bluetooth settings first in Android activity
and then to close the activity and initialize libgdx.

The following code crashes:

```
public class MyActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    public void onCreate (android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);

        initialize(new MyGame(), false); //run libgdx
    }
}
```

StartActivity is as follows (later it'll be game title and bluetooth settings):

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Hello World, Android");
        setContentView(text);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {};
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

No crash message, but app stays with black screen (even no "hello" message)
if I add the following :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

There is "E/AndroidRuntime(612): ERROR: thread attach failed" in logcat.
But as I said no crash message.

Something is wrong here...
I don't know how to write such code correctly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not going to work anyway, but I'd say it is likely crashing due to the StartActivity not being declared in the Manifest.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA added <activity android:name=".StartActivity"/> into manifest after creating activity class

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can start an activity before running libgdx. Don't start the libgdx stuff first. Start the Bluetooth settings, then call the `Intent` to start the actual game when ready.

Like this:

```
public class BluetoothActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetoothsettings);
        Button startGame = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStartGame);

        // handle set start click
        startGame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
                BluetoothActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then your game activity can just be the normal one that extends `AndroidApplication` like you have above.

And of course make sure your `AndroidManifest.xml` starts `BluetoothActivity` first, not libgdx.

```
<activity android:name=".BluetoothActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I was wondering something similar.  Can one say just use parts of libgdx like animations in say a Activity header or footer?  If not can you navigate from Libgdx screen to an activity? back and forth?

Comment: @CodeDroid I know you can use libgdx as one `Activity` among several, and I know you can go back and forth. The way I did it was by using an android `Activity` for a main menu, then libgdx for a game. If the user pressed the back button, the android system unloads the current `Activity` (libgdx) and reloads the next in the stack (main menu). I wouldn't think you could just do a header or footer since libgdx runs off of OpenGL ES, although I don't know that for sure.

Comment: @SteveBlackwell I used the exact same technique you have mentioned above, but when I come back to the libgdx activity I am getting a blank screen!! Any ideas?

Check the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009621/blank-black-screen-while-shifting-between-activities-android