# Blank black screen while shifting between activities android

Tags: android, libgdx

Hi Guys I have 2 activities, 1 is in Android Native(Extends Activity) and 2 is in LIBGdx extends AndroidApplication.

I go from activity 1 to activity 2 and then come back to activity 1 by pressing the back key, then I come back to activity 2 again. This time activity 2 is black and black in color.

Does it has anything to do with libgdx or its an android issue?

Thanks

Comment: Check logcat maybe its because of you are doing long process on main thread.

Comment: @Prachi I checked log cat, nothing fishy there. Is there a way to destroy the activity and everything related to it when I press the back key?

Comment: try to call finish() method ..

Comment: @Prachi tried it. No use!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like libGdx is losing the openGL context. libgdx will get this back automatically when the app goes out of focus (incoming phone call, user presses home key, etc) and then comes back into focus, but here the app never loses focus--only the activity does--so libgdx doesn't know to restore itself.

Does the user need to go back to the first screen? If not, I would mark the first activity `android:noHistory="true"` in the manifest. That makes the back button skip the activity, so the app itself will lose focus.

Otherwise, put debug statements in your ApplicationListener's  `create()`, `resume()`, `pause()`, and `dispose()` methods so we can see how that life cycle is playing out.

Comment: Thanks Steve, you are right, as the libgdx lose its focus, it loses all its textures,skins and fonts which I was storing in a singleton class. I understood it when I made the background red. Anyways I need the first activity, I neither can remove it from my application nor do android:noHistoty = true, instead I flushed and recreated all my textures, skins and fonts at initialize everytime. Now its works fine :)