# Adding libgdx to an Android Native Application

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a simple kids app which teaches things such as colors, numbers, etc... which I am currently developing. It uses what I would consider "standard android java programming (Single Xml/java class)." I also have a simple game with a Dinosaur that jumps over letters using libgdx.

My question is, I would like to have the game as part of the "overall" app. I would like to know if it is even possible to add a libgdx game to an android native application. I tried adding the appropriate files to my app, but this caused a compile error, could someone point me to a place where I could find help on this issue, or perhaps let me know if what I am wanting to do is even possible? Thanks.

---To clairify, my main app has a menu which takes you to activities. I would like the libgdx game to be one of the activities.

---Edit to response---I compile using Gradle and have more errors than I can count. I've since removed the libgdx game from the app so I am not sure of specific errors, but iirc there were over 100, many of which were R issues, which I could have figured out, but I couldn't find anything on either S.O. or the web saying it was even possible to add libgdx to a non-libgdx app.

Comment: It'd help your chances at getting an answer if you 1) show how you compiled the app (a Gradle file) and 2) actually said what the errors were

Comment: Added an edit, as per your comment. :)

Comment: Considering you have a single Java/xml file, I'd consider going the other way - integrate your app into a libgdx project

Comment: Well, I actually have about 15 different activities in the app all accesed from the main menu :/ but, I was actually considering moving them to libgdx as you said. I just have not used libgdx enough to be comfortable with it. I have heard that using lib is hard to get standard apps to work correctly. Have you had any experience with this issue?

Comment: I've seen multiple questions on this site with rather large Gradle files for libgdx Android projects, so I'm sure it's possible, I've just never done it myself

Comment: If you're sure it is possible, then I will continue my research. Thank you for your time. I don't use Stack very often as I have a few good programming friends which are professionals. I apreciate all your help and will continue my research.

Comment: Good luck. And like I said, try getting a simple libgdx project going, then try to merge some code together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate your App with your libgdx game.
    `AndroidLauncher.java` is your libgdx Activity and you can move from one activity to another using Intent.

```
intent = new Intent(this, AndroidLauncher.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and movement from libgdx `AndroidLauncher.java`, you need to call it from inside the core project classes. You need to use an interface.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

If your game is sub view of your App.
The AndroidApplication class (which extends activity) has a method named `initializeForView(ApplicationListener, AndroidApplicationConfiguration)` that will return a View you can add to your layout.

**Pros.**-Code is already you have,only you need to integrate.
**Cons.**-you need to maintain OpenGL Context Loss. Libgdx do for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Libgdx your entire game is just a single Activity. You can start it as any other activity from your code.
Please follow [Can I run an Activity before running libgdx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474766/can-i-run-an-activity-before-running-libgdx) for details.