# Mini-Game inside Android Studio layout

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm quite new to the programming field, but I've become familiar with the Android Studio. I am planning to make a game which is mostly static and I can create it with Android Studio's layouts, but in one of them, I want to add some kind of game engine. Is it possible to implement some kind of LibGDX code into one of the layouts or do I have to make all the game with the LibGDX?

For example - There are several different layouts and in one of them is some kind of box in which there is this mini-game which requires engine.

P.S. I have only created static apps/games so far with layouts and simple logic. Sorry if this question seems stupid or whatever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding libgdx to an Android Native Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923715/adding-libgdx-to-an-android-native-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't integrate LibGDX like that. You will need to use the [Android API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement all screens using LibGDX library if you want to use LibGDX engine. You can't integrate both.
OR
Use Android graphics API to implement your code.