# Which 2d game engine for a crossplatform module inside native appp

Tags: java, android, libgdx, cocos2d-x, game-engine

I'm making a game which is a native application for Android/iOS, but I want to add a 2d graphic module there. Which library should I use? Cocos2d-x, LibGDX, other? Looking for something crossplatform. It's not gonna be a heavy module, so would prefer something lighweight, so it launches quickly, just like a regular native Activity.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say about about cocos, because I've never worked with it. But I've worked with libgdx making a desktop pacman game for a class project (You can check out what the code looks like [over at the repo](https://github.com/YonahKarp/PacMan-Project)). I've found it to work great on desktop, but haven't deployed it to android or iOS. The framework is great (aside for a slightly lacking `Sound`/`Audio` class)

Hope this helps

Comment: I second libGDX.

Answer (score 1):

**You can develop complete App using these framework without any concern with native App development.**

[libGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) and [Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) both are cross platform development engine. If you're good in Java go with LibGdx otherwise if you've good knowledge of c++ then go with Cocos2d-x.

For integration with Android Native App, libGdx is better because you can easily call Android platform code through [interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) but if you choose cocos2d-x then you need to use jni, that is slightly tough to use with objects.

Take a look of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41924604/3445320) that clear, integration having some cons.

Comment: How that looks for iOS with libGDX?

Comment: I don't have enough idea on cross platforming with iOS native App but seems development time will increase very high like, Firstly you've to develop Android Native App then iOS and again integration with both developed App.

Comment: Don't take it into consideration.